# Storing API data from requests in Rails App?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter

I'd like to make requests to APIs for a range of sites like Twitter, Facebook etc and store the results in my database.

The example request Twitter give is here: 
https://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=TwitterAPI&include_entities=true

How do I go about making the request from my Rails 3 App and then store the data? I don't necessarily need all of the data, i'm mostly interested in followers in this case.

Many thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I tried adding this to my artists controller's show method:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'json'
result = JSON.parse(open("https://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=thesubways&include_entities=true").read)

parsed_json = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(result)
@results = parsed_json["followers_count"]
```

Comment: Nothing yet! Loads of other stuff to code while I try and find a good guide to doing this. Are you looking as well or do you have some pointers?

Comment: so you have followers_count in @result? Does this action work  or you get some error ?  what do you need to do next ?

Comment: I thought i'd have to parse then extract the followers count; that's why i've added the last two lines, but these produce a 'can't convert hash into string' error.

Comment: I've also tried replacing the last two lines with `@result = result["followers_count"]` and then I try to display this in my show view with `<%= @result %>` but nothing happens?

Comment: You should not use  ActiveSupport::JSON.decode , because you already have valid ruby hash

Comment: `result = JSON.parse(open("https://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=thesubways&include_entities=true").read)

@results = result["followers_count"]`

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Then it seems the issue is with passing @results to my view!?! When I run through this, using the same lines of code in console I can the correct follower count but nothing when in my show view. Using `<%= @results.inspect %>` in my view returns nil.

Comment: I've cracked it!! I moved the code above into it's own def then called that with before filter. Works perfectly now :) Thanks for your help Fivell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for start ....

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'json'
result = JSON.parse(open("https://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=TwitterAPI&include_entities=true").read)
# now you have result["followers_count"] ... and can use it to store with AR object or raw sql query
```

you also must use database in your rails project, but first of all you should read official guide
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Comment: Thanks for this. I can get it to work in the Rails Console but i'm not sure where or how to incorporate this into my app so that I can both display the results (or single entity like 'followers_count') in my views and be able to save to my DB. If anyone can help or provide a link to a good tutorial it would be really appreciated.

Comment: you should read official guide first of all, I  updated my answer

Comment: I have, maybe i'm just being thick? Appreciate your help though.

Comment: I can help you if you tried something and can  add your source code.